# Using query result data for another query

Tags: mysql, subquery

The following query works for me. However, is there a way to speed it up (table1/2 contain each more than 300000 entries). I also would like to query more data in the subquery and use the distance just to filter results. The two tables have not much in common except the lat/lon.

```
SELECT `lat1`, 
       `lon1`, 
       (SELECT Sqrt(Pow( 69.1 * ( `lat1` - `lat2` ), 2 ) 
                    + Pow( 69.1 * ( `lon2` - `lon1` ) * Cos( `lat` / 57.3 ), 2 ) 
               ) AS 
               distance 
        FROM   table1 
        ORDER  BY distance 
        LIMIT  0, 1) AS `test` 
FROM   `table2`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect that a range query would speed things up

Comment: adding filters (where) seem to slow it down even more.